# getting error in Registration screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

account is not registering and it is already in use the snackbar is working when i am connected with usb and run the code but when i am generating apk file the snackbar and signin is not working i added all the details in my gradle file like storefile progaurd file everything with **`signingConfig signingConfigs.release`** key too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

i added this permission

```
  class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
    }
    
    class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var email = "";
      var password = "";
      var confirmpassword = "";
    
      final emailController = TextEditingController();
      final passwordController = TextEditingController();
      final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
        final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
        String? validateEmail(String value) {
        Pattern pattern =
            r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
        RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern as String);
        if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Enter Valid Email';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        emailController.dispose();
        passwordController.dispose();
        confirmPasswordController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      registration() async {
        if (password == confirmpassword) {
          try {
            UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(userCredential);
            }
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              content: Text(
                "Registered Successfully. Logged In..",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ));
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartQuiz()));
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
              if (kDebugMode) {
                print(" Account Already in use");
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  content: Text(
                    "Account Already in use",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ));
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Password and Confirm Password doesn't match");
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              content: Text(
                "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ));
          }
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 800,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                "images/data7.png",
                              ),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 300,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                "images/d9.png",
                              ),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 20, horizontal: 30),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          spreadRadius: 7,
                                          blurRadius: 10,
                                          offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2))
                                    ]),
                                child: TextField(
                                  autofocus: false,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Email",
                                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.email,
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 188, 255),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                                  controller: emailController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          spreadRadius: 7,
                                          blurRadius: 10,
                                          offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2))
                                    ]),
                                child: TextField(
                                  autofocus: false,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.lock,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 188, 255),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                                    errorStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                  controller: passwordController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          spreadRadius: 7,
                                          blurRadius: 10,
                                          offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2))
                                    ]),
                                child: TextField(
                                  autofocus: false,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Confirm Password",
                                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.lock,
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 188, 255),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                                  controller: confirmPasswordController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        // Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
                                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            email = emailController.text;
                                            password = passwordController.text;
                                            confirmpassword =
                                                confirmPasswordController.text;
                                          });
                                          registration();
                                        }
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                            gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                              colors: [
                                                Color(0xFFACB6E5),
                                                Color(0xFF86FDE8)
                                              ],
                                            )),
                                        width: 190,
                                        height: 60,
                                        child: const Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Sign Up',
                                            style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ,fontSize: 21.0, color: Colors.indigo),                                    ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Already have an Account? ",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo.shade300),
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () => {
                                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                context,
                                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                                  pageBuilder: (context, animation1,
                                                          animation2) =>
                                                      const LoginPage(),
                                                  transitionDuration:
                                                      const Duration(seconds: 0),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            },
                                        child: const Text(
                                          'Login here',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                                        ))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you rephrase your question? I didn't understand your problem clearly.

Comment: user is not signin after clicking signin button when i am generating apk file but when i am connecting usb wire the program is working properly

Comment: did it crash when run in apk?

Comment: no its working properly

Comment: only the issue is snackbar is not working

Comment: not working mean not displaying?

Comment: is it navigated to the StartQuiz screen when pressing the register button?

Comment: The problem might be because of missing SHA certificate fingerprint in your google console. Navigate to project settings in your console and add a SHA key of your computer. Hope it helps!

Comment: i have added sha key

Comment: WOW! this is new. Do this. Take a break. Afterwards, come back and dedicate like 1-2 hours, follow up your authentication process and confirm all required securities are added to firebase and the app. 

This way you will be able to point out a mistake!